# JSON - parsing independently named sub-objects

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am working with the VirusTotal API attempting to write a script that will scan and report findings. The issue I'm having is with the SCANS section of the code, I can extract how many are positive or not but was wanting to output each positive scan and the result (virus name, phishing etc).

Example JSON:

```
{
'response_code': 1,
'verbose_msg': 'Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object',
'scan_id':'1db0ad7dbcec0676710ea0eaacd35d5e471d3e11944d53bcbd31f0cbd11bce31-1390467782',
'permalink': 'https://www.virustotal.com/url/__urlsha256__/analysis/1390467782/',
'url': 'http://www.virustotal.com/',
'scan_date': '2014-01-23 09:03:02',
'filescan_id': null,
'positives': 0,
'total': 51,
'scans': {
      'CLEAN MX': {
      'detected': false,
      'result': 'clean site'
       },
      'MalwarePatrol': {
      'detected': false,
      'result': 'clean site'
      }
 }
 }
```

The code I wrote doesn't seem to pass all the scans info into the loop the only thing I can seem to access is the AV scanner name not detected/result information for each. First time working with JSON api so any assistance is appreciated.

```
params = {'apikey': apikey, 'resource':line}
response = requests.get(vt_report_url, params=params)
result = response.json()

if result['positives'] != "0":
    print "malware detection"
    for avList in result['scans']:
        if avList[1] == 'true':
            print str(avList[0]) + " - "+ str(avList[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code I can see that `scans` is an dict so you need to loop through it using `dict.items()`.

**Code:**

```
params = {'apikey': apikey, 'resource':line}
response = requests.get(vt_report_url, params=params)
result = response.json()

if result['positives'] != 0:
    print "malware detection" 
    for key, value in result['scans'].items():
        if value['detected'] == False:
            print str(key) + " - "+ str(value['result'])
```

**Output:**

```
malware detection
CLEAN MX {'detected': False, 'result': 'clean site'}
```

Comment: I gave this code a go and it initially looked like it would work but it is not passing the items down into an array like I was expecting. I was getting a keyerror on the if statement so I print out the value prior to the check and it is not splitting the items up as expected it is returning a single line of `{u'detected': False, u'result': u'clean site'}`

Comment: @nilats you never mentioned what output you needed.

Comment: Fair enough, my goal was to extract the AV name and the result in the format of "CLEAN MX - clean site" /n "MalwarePatrol - clean site" for each of the various scans

Comment: @nilats check my code, one thing, I changed `'positives': 2` or else the code will not enter the first if condition.

Comment: this code was just example using the example JSON from the VT api site, the code I'm working with is scanning a known malicious link didn't want to include it. So that positives is not an issue overall. Thanks

Comment: @nilats If it works then fine, just note that python variables like this `val =
 {"test": 123}` are dicts and if you want to iterate through them you need `for key,value in val.items()`, if you want to access a particular value then `val["test"]`, the approach you took will only work for an array which looks like this `var = [1,2,3]`